# Checkbox column for multiple rows when shift keyboard modifier is applied

Tags: wpf, checkbox

I have a view model that contains an "IsChecked" property.  This property is bound to a DataGrid RowHeaderTemplate.

I'd like to be able to hold down the shift + ctrl keyboard modifiers to allow for multiple checkbox values to be updated.

For example: If you check the checkbox in the first row, hold down shift, and check the checkbox in the 5th row; rows 1-5 would then have a checked checkbox.

Below is the row header template:

```
<DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <CheckBox VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
                  IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
```

I've tried several combinations of capturing PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown and KeyPress events, but I'm not sure this is even possible with a bound property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've come up with a solution by listening to the IsChecked property changed.  This does the trick for my needs.

```
    private void OnItemOnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs propertyChangedEventArgs)
    {
            ItemViewModel newCheckedItem = sender as ItemViewModel;

            int newCheckedItemIndex = _items.IndexOf(newCheckedItem);

            if ((Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift)) && newCheckedItemIndex != _lastCheckedItemIndex)
            {
                int start = Math.Min(_lastCheckedItemIndex, newCheckedItemIndex);
                int end = Math.Max(_lastCheckedItemIndex, newCheckedItemIndex);

                int countToTake = end - start;

                var itemsToCheck = _items.Skip(start).Take(countToTake).ToList();

                foreach (ItemViewModel itemToCheck in itemsToCheck)
                {
                    // Unhook the property changed event so we don't enter this method again
                    itemToCheck.PropertyChanged -= OnItemOnPropertyChanged;

                    itemToCheck.IsChecked = true;
                    // Re-register the proeprty changed event so that if we're unchecked/re-checked, we can respond.
                    itemToCheck.PropertyChanged += OnItemOnPropertyChanged;
                }

                _lastCheckedItemIndex = -1;
            }
            else
            {
                _lastCheckedItemIndex = newCheckedItemIndex;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: nice solution, I had something similar in mind, just didn't came out as code.

Answer (score -1):

I have faced the same problem and implemented solution somehow similar to what Michael G presented, but more straightforward. Frankly speaking I could not make the `OnPropertyChanged` event to work correctly so I developed the following solution:

XAML:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="_dg_DatasZones" Grid.Row="4" ItemsSource="{Binding}" LoadingRow="_dg_DatasZones_LoadingRow" Style="{StaticResource StandardGrid}" IsReadOnly="False"
                 SelectionMode="Single" >
          <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn CommonClasses:DataGridTemplateColumnStyleExtensions.Style="{StaticResource DataGridColumnIcon}">
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox Name="_CheckBox_SelectAllZone" Click="_CheckBox_SelectAllZone_Click" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
              <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                  <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Checked="Zone_Checked" />
                </DataTemplate>
              </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black" Width="50" Binding="{Binding Id}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextStyle}" Header="ID" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True"  />
            <DataGridTextColumn Foreground="Black" MinWidth="100" Binding="{Binding Name}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextStyle}" Header="ZoneName" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource DataGridHeaderStyle}" IsReadOnly="True" />

          </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Make sure that `SelectionMode="Single"`

C# code:

```
    int _lastSelectedZoneIndex = -1;
    private void Zone_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = _dg_DatasZones.SelectedIndex;
        if (  (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
                 &&  index != _lastSelectedZoneIndex && _lastSelectedZoneIndex >= 0)
        {
            CheckBox chbx = (CheckBox)sender;
            ListCollectionView view = _dg_DatasZones.DataContext as ListCollectionView;
            if (view == null)
                return;
            int startindex = Math.Min(_lastSelectedZoneIndex, index);
            int endindex = Math.Max(_lastSelectedZoneIndex, index);
            for (int i = startindex; i < endindex; i++)
                (view.GetItemAt(i) as TaskZoneData).IsChecked = (chbx.IsChecked == true);
        }
        else
        {
            _lastSelectedZoneIndex = index;
        }
        e.Handled = true;
    }
```

For now this works only for selecting the diapason, but not for unselecting it.
To select, you should check the beginning row (checkbox) then press Shift and check the ending row — and the whole diapason will be selected.